# Trying to solve a MySql error via XAMPP, on my Macbook. All the tutorials and link online are for Windows

Tags: javascript, mysql, macos, xampp

I am trying to solve multiple errors that I receive everytime I try to access "localhost/phpmyadmin" on my browser.

I am using XAMPP to access MySql for a webapp that I am developing for fun. I am kinda new to this and am extremely confused as to why this is happening, as it initally allowed me to create a database but I am suddenly locked out?

It's so frustrating.

I've attached a picture of the error I am receiving and also what my code looks like.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEhjy.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttWK6.jpg)

Please help me!!

The code is here:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const { response } = require('express');
dotenv.config();


app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));


// create
app.post('/insert', (request, response) => {
});



// read
app.get('/getAll',(request,response) => {
    response.json({
        success: true
    });
})

// update 



// delete

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log('App is Running!'));
```

Comment: That error isn't from your code, it's in PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: I understand! How do I fix it in PhpMyAdmin? 

--Also bare with me, it's my first time on here.

Comment: I managed to not get ahead much. So.. I deleted XAMPP and reinstalled. And am starting all over again